# How can i pass parameters to a CURL request in Laravel with package ixudra/curl?

Tags: php, laravel, curl, parameters, request

I'm making a CURL request to fetch response in JSON format using laravel and this package [*ixudra/curl*](https://github.com/ixudra/curl).

The request I'm making is `curl -sX POST https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/addrs?token=YOURTOKEN`

How can the parameters/switches `-sX` be sent with the request using laravel and this package?

Comment: I made the question more explicit- about how it isn't clear how to pass parameters/switches to the curl functions using the function from the package. I also removed the github tag since the tag description contains the text "Do not use this tag for Git-related issues simply because a repository happens to be hosted on GitHub" (refer to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/github/info).

Answer (score 0):

1. The `-s` option is to mute Curl, since you are using the library and running it on backend, you do not need to use this.
2. The `-X POST` option is to use the POST request method, in this case, you just need to chain `->post()` in your code.

   ```
   use Ixudra\Curl\Facades\Curl;

   $response = Curl::to('https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/addrs?token=YOURTOKEN')->post();
   ```